# gmp shared libraries not found

Tags: c, shared-libraries, gmp

I have a very simple GMP program in C (below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main() {
    mpf_t a, b, inter;
    mpf_init(a);
    mpf_init(b);
    mpf_init(inter);
    mpf_set_d(a, 3.0);
    mpf_set_d(b, 5.0);
    mpf_add(inter, a, b);
    gmp_printf("%F+%F=%F\n", a, b, inter);
}
```

For some reason, it compiles alright, but when run, it produces

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `locate libgmp.so.10` yields?

Comment: this: `/usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10
/usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.0.2`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would appear `/usr/local/lib` is not in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*`.

If it is simply run `sudo ldconfig` (or `ldconfig` as root) and try again.

If it is not, either add it or manually override the library path for the command:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./myprogram
```

It does seem your configuration is strange, check that `/usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10` is a link to `/usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.0.2`, e.g.

```
$ ls -ltr /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 2011-07-27 12:15 /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3 -> libgmp.so.3.5.2
```